# Is there any way to make this template in cpp work?

Tags: c++, function, templates, multidimensional-array

Full Code is here: https://pastebin.com/XXutDDjP

The whole project can get a bit messy to post here, but I am confused in the following part.

Check out this code:

```
template <typename T>
T myMax(T x, T y) {
  return (x > y) ? x : y;
}
```

For example, this code matches the arguments,

`myMax(int x, int y)`, `myMax(char x, char y)`, …

so, `T` can replace any data-type like `char`, `double`, `int`, `float`, …

But, I want to use something like:

```
template <typename T>
int myMax(int A[T][T], int n) {
  // ...
}
```

So that it can be used for all matrices of type `A[T][T]`, 
`myMax(A[5][5], 2)`,  `myMax(A[7][7], 5)`, …

Comment: What is `n`? Seems strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow usage of C-style arrays, `std::array`, `std::vector` and other possible custom Matrix classes that overload `operator[]`, I'd use:

```
template <typename T>
int myMax(T const& matrix, int n) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: In principle, you'd hope any object having an `operator[]` interface also provides a means to get its size. Unfortunately, C-style arrays don't... If you don't care about those, you could drop the `int n` parameter completely.

Comment: @rubenvb since we are passing C-arrays with a reference, `sizeof(matrix) * (matrix[0])` should do. However, I left the `int n` in because I wasn't sure what the purpose of that argument was, since no explanation is provided in the question.

Comment: You mean `sizeof(matrix) * sizeof(matrix[0])` I think, but that only works for array literals and not "arrays" passed as pointer-to-first-element. But yeah, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

just change `typename` to `size_t`:

```
template<size_t T>
int myMax(int A[T][T], int n)
{
}
```

Comment: I'd use `auto`: `template<auto T>`

Comment: @Ayxan i don't see why, array sizes are always `size_t`

Comment: pedantically, it's `std::size_t` unless you've included `stddef.h`, did `using std::size_t` or `using namespace std`. But it is common (although not required) for implementations to define `size_t` in the global namespace even if you haven't done any of these, To avoid this common not-totally-portable coding I'd use `template <auto T>` which is guaranteed to always work.

Comment: `template <template T, size_t N>
int myMax(const T (&A)[N][N])` so both sizes is used. and const for correctness. (I assume `int n` should be removed too as we have the size).